# dynamic positioning of listview in android

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to make a layout in android with 2 listviews where  one is the main listview and another is the sublistview. When a user clicks on one of the items in the main list,the sublist will be populated with the list items corresponding to the main list item clicked.

While I am able to have two list view side by side, I am not able to positon the second list(sublist) to the side of the selected item of the first list. Is there a way to dynamically position the second list based upon the first list item selection in android.?

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a Table Layout and position the two lists side by side. You can use the xml design file to place the list views and then in the code view you can dynamically populate the lists...